# `RaiseEvent` called on `BorderedCanvas` does not call event handler

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following C# class:

```
class MouseWheelEventListenerViewManager : ReactViewManager
{

    public override void OnDropViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext, BorderedCanvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDropViewInstance(reactContext, canvas);
        RemoveListeners(canvas);
    }

    protected override BorderedCanvas CreateViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext)
    {
        var borderedCanvas = base.CreateViewInstance(reactContext);
        AddListeners(borderedCanvas);
        return borderedCanvas;
    }

    protected void AddListeners(BorderedCanvas borderedCanvas)
    {
        Console.Write("In AddListeners");
        borderedCanvas.PreviewMouseWheel += PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    protected void RemoveListeners(BorderedCanvas borderedCanvas)
    {
        borderedCanvas.PreviewMouseWheel -= PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    protected static void PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Added PreviewMouseWheel");
        if (!e.Handled)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            var eventArg =
                new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
                {
                    RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent,
                    Source = sender
                };

            UIElement parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((UIElement)sender) as UIElement;
            parent?.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
        }
    }

}
```

This code achieves what it's supposed to do in my application(allow scrolling on top of a ScrollViewer), so I believe it is correct. However, I don't know how to test it.

I added this test which should check that a `MouseWheelEvent` is marked as `handled`:

```
    [Test]
    public void MouseWheelEvent_is_marked_as_handled()
    {

        var invoked = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var mouseWheelEventListenerViewManager = new MouseWheelEventListenerViewManager();

        BorderedCanvas canvas = mouseWheelEventListenerViewManager.CreateView(new ThemedReactContext(new ReactContext()));

        MouseWheelEventArgs me = new MouseWheelEventArgs(InputManager.Current.PrimaryMouseDevice, 10, 10)
        {
            RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseWheelEvent
        };
        canvas.RaiseEvent(me);

        Assert.True(invoked.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20)));
        invoked.Set();
        Assert.IsTrue(me.Handled);
   }
```

This test fails at `Assert.IsTrue(me.Handled)`and only this is printed on the console:

```
In AddListeners
```

Normally, this should be printed:

```
In AddListeners
Added PreviewMouseWheel
```

This means that the method `PreviewMouseWheel` is not called from the test, even though `AddListeners` was called, which means that `canvas.PreviewMouseWheel` was initialised.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: `Assert.IsTrue(me.Handled)`

Comment: No surprise here. You don't raise a `Mouse.PreviewMouseWheelEvent`, so why do you expect your PreviewMouseWheel handler being called? ;-)